# Error: Uncaught [TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, react-testing-library

I am using React testing library and I am getting the following error

> Error: Uncaught [TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined" in the last line of my Test.tsx file.

How can  I view if all my components are getting rendered? By Components I mean: Full Name, title, date, and others as per my Abc.tsx file? What should be the parameter such that I can render all the components of my ShowPage?
Because if I only render `<Abc/>` within render it gives me the
error of :

> No overload matches this call.   Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Readonly): ShowPage', gave the following error.
>       Property 'post' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'Readonly'.   Overload 2 of 2, '(props: ShowProps,
>   context?: any): ShowPage', gave the following error.
>       Property 'post' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'Readonly'.

**Test.tsx**

```
export default class Abc extends React.Component < ShowProps > {
  render() {
    ;

    return (
      <div className="Post-description">
          <Title>{post.title}</Title>
          <hr/>
          <Name>
          {`${post.fullName}|${dateToString(currentDateTime)}`}
          </Name>
          <br/>
          <Question>{post.body}</Question>
          <hr/>
          <AllComments/>
      </div>
    ) 
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you didn't add state to your `App.tsx` component or it's a functional component where `this` is undefined.

Comment: Can you add whole Test file as well.

Comment: Done! Please have a look @MuhammadAli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gotcha.
`this.state` should be undefined in your test as test case is not a regular component of react.
Moreover, you should mock your post and pass it as props in your `ShowPage` component while testing. Then you'll be good to go. And I don't think you need Router and Route as wrappers as long as you're not using API from router, i.e history object.

```
const post = {
  fullName: 'Muhammad Ali',
  title: 'Post title',
  body: 'Post body',
  updatedAt: '1/30/2020',
}
const {getByPlaceholderText, queryByTestId} = render(
   <ShowPage post={post}/>
);
```

Comment: That seems fine but for the updatedAt: ' ', I get the output as NaN.